# Why do I get 'return' outside function on the line 6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def getContinue():
 response = input('Do you want to continue (y:n): ')
while response not in ('y', 'n', 'Y', 'N'):
    response = input('Do you want to continue (y:n): ')

if response in ('y', 'Y'):
    return 'y'
else:
    return 'n'
```

Write a Python function named getContinue that displays to the user “Do you want to continue (y/n): ”, and continues to prompt the user until either uppercase or lowercase 'y' or 'n' is entered, returning (lowercase) 'y' or 'n' as the function value.

Comment: I formatted your code, but doesn't seem to be indented correctly. Can you confirm that the indentation is the same as in your code?

Comment: This reads like a homework question.

Comment: I don't understand why, because the `return` outside function is in line 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is just indentation error in your code because when I ran your code it worked fine.

```
def getContinue():
    response = input('Do you want to continue (y:n): ')
    while response not in ('y', 'n', 'Y', 'N'):
        response = input('Do you want to continue (y:n): ')

    if response in ('y', 'Y'):
        return 'y'
    else:
        return 'n'
```

If you are still not able to figure it out please share the link to the question